# Cannot use continue-on-error in a job that uses a reusable workflow

Tags: github-actions

I have a job in a workflow that uses a matrix and a reusable workflow. The workflow runs fine. But I wanted to configure continue-on-error for the job so that if one of the matrix jobs fails, the rest will continue. But seems I cannot add this property to the job. I get the error "Property continue-on-error is not allowed". Following is a sample job.

```
release:
    needs: [xyz]
    if: ${{ needs.xyz.outputs.abc != '[]' }}
    strategy:
      matrix:
        path: ${{ fromJSON(needs.xyz.outputs.abc) }}
    uses: ./.github/workflows/executor.yml
    secrets: inherit
    with:
      dir: matrix.path
```